# Why *don't* I need methods to set or read class attributes?

Tags: javascript, class

In putting together getters and setters I realized that they aren't required.
What am I missing? How to ensure that when i call attributes they are the ones on the class ?

```
'use strict';

const { Book } = require('../app');
const { Page } = require('../page');
const { Bookmark } = require('../bookmark');
//
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

it('has a bookmark', function () {
  let bookmark = new Bookmark('bookmark');
  bookmark.material = 'paper';
  bookmark.mm='a';
  expect(bookmark.mm).to.equal('a');
  expect(bookmark.material).to.equal('paper');
})  

#../bookmark.js
class Bookmark {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

exports.Bookmark = Bookmark;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. They're the "ones on the class" because you're calling it on an instance. Are you asking how to make JavaScript act like a statically-typed-ier language?

Comment: Because javascript doesn't have "attributes", it just has properties, and you can create those arbitrarily on any objects.

Comment: This may be better suited for Typescript but that still wouldn't ensure type safety. However, if I'm understanding your question... you could possibly hand-roll your own [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to throw an exception.

Comment: @Bergi has it.  I come from Ruby and expected to need getters/setters, like with `attr_accessor`.  Do you only use them when u want more than just attributes in javascript ? Or does the same apply for methods, i.e. add them at any time.  ruby is dynamic but helps you avoid typos with attr. a lot of js is adding stuff to DOM objects I guess?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Yes, you use accessors (`get`/`set`) only when you want a property that is not a normal data property. And yes, the same applies for methods, although normally neither are added "*at any time*" but only in a formalised fashion (i.e. in a constructor) - in good code.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant "*a lot of js is adding stuff to DOM objects I guess?*" - no, [that's shunned](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: Once I add the setter with `set ab(value)` then the getter is required